# DD4T 2.2.1 Cache Changes

Tags: dd4t

We have updated DD4T dll's from DD4T 1.x to DD4T 2.2.1. Will this change impact DD4T Caching in any manner?

I went through this post [DD4T 2.0 caching updates](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14374/dd4t-2-0-caching-updates) and what I understood is DD4t 2.2.1 is no more using CacheSettings_CallBackInterval Key to Set the polling interval. Does it mean that after DD4T upgrade to latest it will automatically uses inbuilt event based cache invalidation? I do not need to do anything in Cd_Storage_config.xml or Cd_Deployer_Config.xml file?

Update: In Cd_storage_config.xml file I can see

```
 <ObjectCache Enabled="true">
```

But

```
   <ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="false"/>
```

Does that mean we are not using Default Tridion Object Cache for all the items which are stored using defaultdb, right?

I also don't See any Configuration for ActiveMq and Jms that means we are only relying on Default DD4T Caching, right?

Answer (score 1):

DD4T 1 had a callback mechanism which made sure that items were removed from the DD4T object cache when the pages or component presentations they were based on got republished. This was achieved through a callback method in the cache agent, that was called in the background by a separate thread.
We found that most customers ended up disabling this functionality because it was eating up too many threads.

In DD4T 2 we decoupled the invalidation mechanism from the cache itself. The DD4T core comes with an autonomous cache. Invalidation is provided by a separate Nuget package called DD4T.Caching.ApacheMQ.

Velu Arjunan wrote a very good blog post to get you started: https://velmuruganarjunan.wordpress.com/2018/02/04/how-to-setup-sdl-web-8-deployer-and-dd4t-2-0-net-web-app-with-activemq-caching-invalidation/. The link to the dd4t-cachechannel.jar file in that post is broken, it should be: https://github.com/dd4t/dd4t-cachechannel/blob/develop/dist/dd4t-cachechannel-1.0.jar.

Comment: Thanks for your response, one more thing as Micro services are common for all the solutions but some other solutions might be using DD4T 1 and some are might still use File System (as they are using Dwt based implementation), in this scenario how can we proceed ?

Comment: DD4T 1 does not support Web 8.5, but it is easy enough to build yourself. If you post this as a separate question I can explain it. File system publishing is still supported in Web 8.5 even with microservices, but you need to use the legacy mode (see https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-A3758A5B-8623-4EC5-BC46-459B2E91E39C#docid=GUID-0D330E1A-A753-45D2-B462-3121F756EE14&filename=GUID-0D330E1A-A753-45D2-B462-3121F756EE14.xml&query=&scope=&tid=&resource=&inner_id=&addHistory=true&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-0D330E1A-A753-45D2-B462-3121F756EE14).